DXF internal offset with shapely
I cannot create a internal offset using shapely.
I was trying something like:
def draw_inside_offset1(self, offset=3.0):
    combined_path = self.get_contour_path()
    offset_path = combined_path.buffer(-3.0, join_style=2, cap_style=1, mitre_limit=5.0, resolution=16)
    simplified_offset = offset_path.simplify(0.01)
    #fixed_offset = self.fix_corners(simplified_offset)
    fixed_offset = Polygon(simplified_offset)
    if fixed_offset.geom_type == 'Polygon':
        x, y = fixed_offset.exterior.xy

        line, = self.ax.plot(x, y, color='r', linewidth=1)
    elif fixed_offset.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
        for polygon in fixed_offset.geoms:
            x, y = polygon.exterior.xy
            line, = self.ax.plot(x, y, color='r', linewidth=1)

    self.canvas.draw()

    return fixed_offset`

But it does not generate anything. 
My contour returned by get_contour_path() is made of lines and arcs.
Code attached. I'm expecting to see an internal offset similar to the outside offset
